# Android Studio doesn't show layout

Tags: android, android-studio

[API unknown and layout doesn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucXg8.png)

API Unknown and layout doesn't show , please help me to fix it

Comment: Your gradle sync failed, check error and try again after fix it.

Comment: did you install Android API ? also add Gradle error.

Comment: Build your gradle. If it fails, try and resolve or paste the error along with the question

Answer (score 0):

You have a Gradle error. When there are Gradle errors, you will experience issues with rendering. However, in my experience having a Gradle error only causes problems with external libraries. So did you install the Android SDK?

This is only the basic solution, and I will be able to give you a more accurate answer when you add the Gradle error to your question.